# Como restringir minutos em um intervalo de tempo utilizando MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela que contem dia, mes, ano, hora, minuto e segundo. Preciso retornar apenas o horário entre 8 e 11 horas, porém não quero que me retorne das 11 adiante Exemplo: 8:01 8:40 9:40 10:02 10:55 11:00 não quero que retorne 11:01, 11:10...

```
 SELECT *
    FROM oi_fact.metrics_values mv
             JOIN oi_fact.dim_date dd ON mv.dtt_id = dd.dtt_id
    WHERE dmm_id in (select dmm_id from dim_metric where met_id IN (1136))
      and mv.nod_id = 168992
      AND mv.dtt_id between '202101010000' AND '202101302300'
      AND dd.hour >= 8 and dd.hour <= 11
    order by mv.dtt_id;
```

Comment: Algo como `dd.hour < 11 OR (dd.hour = 11 and dd.minute = 0 and dd.second = 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma sugestão para testes:

```
  AND dd.hour * 10000 + dd.minute * 100 + dd.second between 80000 and 110000
```

Espero que ajude